# Tail call recursion

Tags: c++, tail-recursion

I'm implementing a function as following:

```
void Add(list* node)
{
    if(this->next == NULL)
        this->next = node;
    else
        this->next->Add(node);
}
```

As it seems `Add` is going to be tail-called in every step of the recursion.
I could also implement it as:

```
void Add(list *node)
{
    list *curr = this;
    while(curr->next != NULL) curr = curr->next;
    curr->next = node;
}
```

This will not use recursion at all.
Which version of this is better? (in stack size or speed)
Please don't give the "Why don't use STL/Boost/whatever?" comments/answers.

Comment: So this is basically recursion vs iterative?

Comment: @quasiverse its tail-recursion vs. iterative. (there is a huge difference)

Comment: If you avoid recursion your stack can't grow crazily, but any half-decent compiler from the last 20 years ought to handle tail call recursion sensibly for you anyway

Answer (score 7, accepted):

They probably will be the same performance-wise, since the compiler will probably optimise them into the exact same code.

However, if you compile on Debug settings, the compiler will not optimise for tail-recursion, so if the list is long enough, you can get a stack overflow. There is also the (very small) possibility that a bad compiler won't optimise the recursive version for tail-recursion. There is no risk of that in the iterative version.

Pick whichever one is clearer and easier for you to maintain taking the possibility of non-optimisation into account.

Answer (score 5):

I tried it out, making three files to test your code:

#### node.hh:

```
struct list {
  list *next;
  void Add(list *);
};
```

#### tail.cc:

```
#include "node.hh"

void list::Add(list* node)
{
    if(!this->next)
        this->next = node;
    else
        this->next->Add(node);
}
```

#### loop.cc:

```
#include "node.hh"

void list::Add(list *node)
{
    list *curr = this;
    while(curr->next) curr = curr->next;
    curr->next = node;
}
```

Compiled both files with G++ 4.3 for IA32, with `-O3` and `-S` to give assembly output rather than object files

### Results:

#### tail.s:

```
_ZN4list3AddEPS_:
.LFB0:
        .cfi_startproc
        .cfi_personality 0x0,__gxx_personality_v0
        pushl   %ebp
        .cfi_def_cfa_offset 8
        movl    %esp, %ebp
        .cfi_offset 5, -8
        .cfi_def_cfa_register 5
        movl    8(%ebp), %eax
        .p2align 4,,7
        .p2align 3
.L2:
        movl    %eax, %edx
        movl    (%eax), %eax
        testl   %eax, %eax
        jne     .L2
        movl    12(%ebp), %eax
        movl    %eax, (%edx)
        popl    %ebp
        ret
        .cfi_endproc
```

#### loop.s:

```
_ZN4list3AddEPS_:
.LFB0:
        .cfi_startproc
        .cfi_personality 0x0,__gxx_personality_v0
        pushl   %ebp
        .cfi_def_cfa_offset 8
        movl    %esp, %ebp
        .cfi_offset 5, -8
        .cfi_def_cfa_register 5
        movl    8(%ebp), %edx
        jmp     .L3
        .p2align 4,,7
        .p2align 3
.L6:
        movl    %eax, %edx
.L3:
        movl    (%edx), %eax
        testl   %eax, %eax
        jne     .L6
        movl    12(%ebp), %eax
        movl    %eax, (%edx)
        popl    %ebp
        ret
        .cfi_endproc
```

Conclusion: The output is substantially similar enough (the core loop/recursion becomes `movl, movl, testl, jne` in both) that it really isn't worth worrying about. There's one less unconditional jump in the recursive version, although I wouldn't want to bet either way which is faster if it's even measurable at all. Pick which ever is most natural to express the algorithm at hand. Even *if* you later decide that was a bad choice it's not too hard to switch.

Adding `-g` to the compilation doesn't change the actual implementation with g++ either, although there is the added complication that setting break points no longer behaves like you would expect it to - break points on the tail call line gets hit at most once (but not at all for a 1 element list) in my tests with GDB, regardless of how deep the recursion actually goes.

### Timings:

Out of curiosity I ran some timings with the same variant of g++. I used:

```
#include <cstring>
#include "node.hh"

static const unsigned int size = 2048;
static const unsigned int count = 10000;

int main() {
   list nodes[size];
   for (unsigned int i = 0; i < count; ++i) {
      std::memset(nodes, 0, sizeof(nodes));
      for (unsigned int j = 1; j < size; ++j) {
        nodes[0].Add(&nodes[j]);
      }
   }
}
```

This was run 200 times, with each of the loop and the tail call versions. The results **with this compiler on this platform** were fairly conclusive. Tail had a mean of 40.52 seconds whereas lop had a mean of 66.93. (The standard deviations were 0.45 and 0.47 respectively).

[image: Box plot of results]

So I certainly wouldn't be scared of using tail call recursion if it seems the nicer way of expressing the algorithm, but I probably wouldn't go out of my way to use it either, since I suspect that these timing observations would most likely vary from platform/compiler (versions).